# Vue + Backend - use Laravel or learn NodeJS

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

I am working for system for our event. It is basically registration for photo shoots. Models sends invitation to photographers and conversely. Photograher accepts, they setup place, time, have inside messenger etc.

System in now full in Laravel and I start writing it from scratch. Now additional it will have mobile apps and push notifications and some websocket for real time refresh.

I want frontend in Vue, and now wonder for backend. I have good knowledge about Laravel, standard about JavaScript and never work with Node and about 6 months for do this project.

On my place do you choose Laravel or learning NodeJS ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: If you are comfortable enough with node environment, I think u should go for nuxt(https://nuxtjs.org/) which is awesome, You would get tons of features and experience new dev tools and new js trends.

Comment: It's up to you. What you can do in Node, you can probably do in Laravel too. But if you are looking for a subjective opinion I'd say go for Node. It has tons of features, it's easy to learn, frameworks like ExpressJs and ORMs like Sequelize have solid documentations and there are tons of step-by-step guides available on youtube or programming websites.

Comment: you can even make a set up to use both... obviously you would use node just for things like implementing notifications (socket.io) and stuff like that. Laravel offers a great set up to work with vue js... i really don't have much experience making backends with node, so i think i might not be impartial. I'm just talking about a set up that could work. Given the things you already know... i would do heavy things with laravel, and learn only what you need for node (you can learn more... but at least what you need XD)

Comment: dziraf, of course, I search for peoples subject opinions, wonder how You will do things ;). Erubiel Do you think that doing both node and laravel can work ?

Comment: Have you considered a no backend solution like firebase?  I've been using it for a webstore I'm writing in vue.js and I love it.  It's nice to worry almost entirely about the front end and the updates from the realtime database are a nice addition.  The only backends I've written have been in C# so I dont have any experience with Laravel or NodeJS backends.